# Fine Grained Memory Checker for CUDA?

Tags: debugging, cuda

I suspect I have a fine grained memory error in a large CUDA kernel I'm running.  Device side printf is showing some varying values on variables that should be deterministic.  The "stable" version of the CUDA development tools I'm using removed device emulation mode, and its version of cuda-gdb doesn't work with templated functions.  Cuda-memcheck runs, but doesn't catch anything.

On the cpu I would use valgrind or electric fence to catch memory errors like this.  What neat tricks are there for debugging memory errors if all you have available is printf?

For example, is there a way to flood the entire memory space with nans and use printfs to find where they first pop up in my computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of thing, I like to allocate the whole available global memory space, then manange the memory myself. Use a custom memset function to set the whole allocation to recognisable word sized bit pattern, then initialize blocks within the allocation for your kernel to use. If you implement a simple device side assert to trap that bit pattern and report thread, block, line where it shows up, you should be able to isolate out of bounds global memory reads that cuda-memcheck doesn't catch.

Comment: If you leave some gaps between your allocations, this is basically implementing the electric-fence library yourself.  One downside is that if you really allocate the whole available memory space, you're limiting yourself to one cuda app per gpu.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's almost possible to implement libefence, assuming you're doing all of your allocation on the host; you just have to trap cudaMalloc and cudaFree using a LD_PRELOAD hack.  The only thing missing would be the ability to mark the padded regions as unreadable/unwriteable so that you segfault automatically whenever you go out of bounds.

Comment: @Drew Wagner: you could allocate less that the whole gou memory if you want. CUDA-memcheck or the runtime can trap things that would hose VRAM or another apps space. I just allocated it all because I tend to work on big linear algebra problems which need every byte they can get.